# Random Image Shortcode

Tags: images, shortcode

I have a great little shortcode for displaying random images. Works wonderflly--however, the output defaults to the upper corner of the main container element--as though it is being written after the entire page is done and the image path is written in that template (always shows below header but at the top of page).

I have tried wrapping the image code and working with other fixes but am hitting my head against the wall as to why this won't write inline with my content.

in functions.php:

```
function random_image() {

$dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/WHATEVERYOURPATHIS/";
if (is_dir($dir)) :

    $dir_list = array_diff(scandir($dir), array(".", "..", ".svn"));

    $dir_list = array_values($dir_list);

$output .= "<img src='".WP_CONTENT_URL."/WHATEVERYOURPATHIS/{$dir_list[mt_rand(0,count($dir_list)-1)]}'>";
echo $output;
endif;
} 
add_shortcode('largerandomimage', 'random_image');
```

This is an easy way for my content editors to be able to insert a variety of random images from select galleries areas.

Any thoughts/recommendations on why this code, in particular, is displaying incorrectly would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what it outputs?

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo--not a duplicate but similar, I didn't see that post on my searches earlier. I'll try the recommended use of return vs. echo.